# Span of Control: 5-7 direct subordinates of one manager

Tags: psychology, work, management

I keep hearing about "ideal" number of direct subordinates, which is 5 to 7.
It's also called "Span of control"

> **Span of control**, also known as span of management, is a human resources management term that refers to the number of subordinates a supervisor can effectively manage. [Source]

The concept and the number dated back to 1922:

> In studies of British military leaders, Hamilton found that they could
>   not effectively control more than three to six people directly. These
>   figures have been generally accepted as the "rule of thumb" for span
>   of control ever since. [Source]

Was it tested or topic additionally researched in Information Technologies era ?

Comment: I have heard a similar claims about 3-7 participants role-playing game groups. In my experience, it is correct.